# Spring security authenticating error

Tags: spring, hibernate, security, spring-security

I have an application which I have configured so I can use database to authenticate users.

Trying to login as either user or admin with the set up username and password gives this error:

```
  HTTP Status 404 - /project/login_error.jsp
```

So I tried to see if my url were working manually by putting the links in the navigation bar, the admin page comes up when I use this link:

```
   https://localhost:8443/project/admin
```

Some other page also come up when entered manually, others do not show but gives me the error page.

The home page on the other hand does not show at all when I use this:

```
 https://localhost:8443/project/home
```

It does not give any error but just redirects back to the login page.

No error comes up in the stack trace except for the hibernate HQL.

The security config:

```
  <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
  <http pattern="/resources/css/**" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/login.jsp*" security="none"/>

 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/denied"   

  authentication-manager-ref="authManager">

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll" requires-

     channel='https'/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" requires-

   channel='https'/>
    <intercept-url pattern='/home' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-

   channel='https'/> 
    <intercept-url pattern='/admin' access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-

   channel='https'/>

    <form-login login-page='/login' login-processing-url='/j_spring_security_check' 
  always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-
  url="/login_error.jsp?error=true"/>   

    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url='/login' /> 
   </http>


<authentication-manager id="authManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="***UserDetailsService">
    <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="**UserDetailsService" class="com.**.**.**.**UserDetailsService">
</beans:bean>
```

Controller

```
  @Controller
  public class ApplicationController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home(ModelMap model) {
    logger.info("Download and Upload Page {}.");

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";

}


      @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String login(ModelMap model) {
    logger.info("This is the login page {}.");

    return "login";

 }
```

Jsp page

```
   <c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="loginUrl"/>  
   <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" >
<label for="j_username">Username</label>
<input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" />

<label for="j_password">Password</label>
<input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" />

   <input  type="submit"   
   value="Login"/>                              

    </form>
```

The HQL that shows in the output

```
   Hibernate: select login0_.person_id as person1_1_, login0_1_.manager_id as      

   manager4_1_, login0_1_.email as email1_, login0_1_.name as name1_, login0_.enabled 

   as enabled3_, login0_.password as password3_, login0_.user_id as user5_3_, 

   login0_.username as username3_ from users login0_ inner join person login0_1_ on 

   login0_.person_id=login0_1_.person_id where login0_.username=?
```

I don't really know what I'm missing in this implementation. And I would appreciate any pointers on what the problem is.

Edit - adding security filter

```
     <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-
      class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Have you added the security filter?

Comment: Yes I added the security filter. I've also added it to the first post.

Comment: Is it work if you removes `requires-channel='https'` from all places?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying but no it doesn't work when I remove the https. It just outputs that it is loading user with this - loadUserByUsername  :  er45. Then returns the error page. The weird thing is that if I switch to using an in memory xml username/password it works and I can retrieve the homepage, but as soon as I switch to a database hibernate authentication, the error comes up.

Comment: Is this still an issue? From what I get out of the question you use a custom UserDetailsService. You should edit it into the question. The config looks good so far. To make any further assumptions a look into the UserDetailsService seems necessary to me.